# why does kernel image and direct mapping overlap in physical address space?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, virtual-address-space

below is the implementation of transforming virtual addr to physical addr of kernel space. However, by this way the kernel image and direct mapping have overlapped area in physical space.  Is this way of mapping designed by purpose?

```
unsigned long __phys_addr(unsigned long x)
{
    unsigned long y = x - __START_KERNEL_map;

    /* use the carry flag to determine if x was < __START_KERNEL_map */
    if (unlikely(x > y)) {
        x = y + phys_base;

        VIRTUAL_BUG_ON(y >= KERNEL_IMAGE_SIZE);
    } else {
        x = y + (__START_KERNEL_map - PAGE_OFFSET);

        /* carry flag will be set if starting x was >= PAGE_OFFSET */
        VIRTUAL_BUG_ON((x > y) || !phys_addr_valid(x));
    }
```

Comment: Physical and virtual addresses do not overlap because they are never used for the same purpose.

Comment: @stark my question is why two physical address space overlapped with each other, not about virutal and physical

Comment: The function converts a virtual address in the contiguous region based at __START_KERNEL_map to a physical address in the contiguous region based at phys_base. There is only one physical address space here.

Comment: @stark what about the `PAGE_OFFSET` in else clause?